# Problems with PopUpAppender - seems to be 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, appender, log4javascript

I try to include the `log4javascript` JS library within my project and therefore followed a quick example to configure a simple named `logger` object with a `PopUpAppender` and I'm seeing the same message over and over again:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focusPopUp' of undefined
```

which points to the follwing line within the `PopUpAppender` function:

```
function PopUpAppender(lazyInit, initiallyMinimized, useDocumentWrite,
                               width, height) {
            this.create(false, null, lazyInit, initiallyMinimized,
                    useDocumentWrite, width, height, this.defaults.focusPopUp); // this is were the error seems to happen...
        }
```

So, I created a simple `HTML` project with just a `index.html` plain `html` site and including `log4javascript.js` and `log4javascript_uncompressed.js` alternately to test if the behaviour is different in any of the files. But everytime I try to initialize the `logger` object in the described way, I see the same error.

If I step back and try to initialize the `logger` in the simplest way possible, like:

```
var log = log4javascript.getDefaultLogger();
```

everything works fine and I see the logger output popping up and write out my first log message.

Am I doing something wrong within my try on initializing a `logger` object? I can't see any stumbling block as I'm basically doing the same as the `log4javascript.getDefaultLogger()` method does:

```
log4javascript.getDefaultLogger = function() {
        if (!defaultLogger) {
            defaultLogger = log4javascript.getLogger(defaultLoggerName);
            var a = new log4javascript.PopUpAppender();
            defaultLogger.addAppender(a);
        }
        return defaultLogger;
    };
```

Any hints on this?

---

EDIT:

I initialize my `logger` this way

```
var log = log4javascript.getLogger("main");
var appender = log4javascript.PopUpAppender();
log.addAppender(appender);
log.debug("Logging is enabled!");
```

---

EDIT 2:

So, I started a new plain HTML project with only the `index.html` page and the `js` folder, which is the extracted folder from the `log4javascript` *.zip package.

This is my whole HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Log4Javascript Tryout Page!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/log4javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var logger = log4javascript.getLogger('main');
        var appender = log4javascript.PopUpAppender();
        logger.addAppender(appender);
        logger.debug('Logging enabled!');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and still I keep getting the same error...?

Comment: This sounds like a log4javascript bug, although quite a surprising one if so. Could you add the code you're using to initialize the logger?

Comment: @TimDown thanks for your answer - I added the code above (within the 'edit' section). this behaviour is also very suprising for me, as I'm initializing the `logger` object in the same way as it's done through the `getDefaultLogger()` method...

Comment: @TimDown I added a (possibly) much clearer code example to show what I'm doing and how I'm initialising `log4javascript`'s `logger` object....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to use `new`:

```
var appender = new log4javascript.PopUpAppender();
```

Comment: @herom: I feel like a dumbass for not spotting it straight away.